# Different encoding in output from Velocity on Windows and Mac OS X

Tags: java, xml, encoding, velocity

All,

once again I find myself in the black hole of confusion that is the topic of encodings.

I have a Java application that given input in the form of a CSV file creates XML files using Velocity. I have gone over the code and as far as I can see I set and use the proper encoding (UTF-8) in all places where I'm supposed to do so. When I run this tool on my own laptop (Mac OS X) everything works as expected and any special characters from the input is written correctly to the XML file. This is also true when I run it on a VMware machine running Windows as its OS. However, when the tool is run on a couple of other machines these special characters are shown as some type of encoded value (and not the good encoding used for XML).

Can the OS/machine itself affect how Java behaves when writing/reading text in this manner? If so, what do I need to do in my code to override this behaviour so that I can be confident?

Regards,
Daniel

Comment: *Can the OS/machine itself affect how Java behaves when writing/reading text in this manner?* Very much so. How are you running this?

Comment: The default encoding depends on the OS. E.g. it is Cp1252 (Windows-ANSI) in Windows and UTF-8 in Linux. I don't know the default encoding in Mac OS but it is likely not Windows ANSI. So you should always use explicit encodings for each conversion between text and bytes. Then the behaviour should be the same on Mac OS and Windows. Maybe the input file's encoding is not what you expect.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, @g00se.

In both cases I ran it as a unit test by running Maven from a command prompt. In one case it was the standard terminal in Mac OS X and from Git Bash on Windows.

Comment: Thanks @vanje! 
The input has been verified and the same goes for the .vm file I use for my Velocity template. So my guess is that I'm doing something wrong in the code. Perhaps there is one more Writer or so that I have to configure.

Do you know if those components will fall back on the OS default encoding unless I tell them otherwise?

Comment: No guessing of encoding goes on, so if you don't tell your code what the input encoding is, any reading will simply use the default encoding. What does `chcp` give you in cmd.exe? And you might tell us what `System.out.println(System.getProperty("file.encoding"));` gives

Comment: Of course, it follows from my last that you need to use the encoding that is correct for your input files. So if they really *are* UTF-8, and it looks like they are as there are no errors in Linux, then you should explicitly read them as such with (at bottom) `reader = new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8");` or some such

Comment: The chcp command on the machine where things fail was _Active code page: 65001_ and on the machines where things worked we got _Active code page: 437_ (and the file.encoding gave us _UTF-8_.

I also think that I found the issue and as so often before it was not in the hardware but rather in the developer. 

I had created a FileWriter like this `fileWriter = new FileWriter(loadFile);` and then user that to create my XML file. I changed this to 

`OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(loadFile);
  fileWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(out, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));`